# How I fix it ? NullPointerException at org.springframework.data.redis.support.atomic.RedisAtomicLong.incrementAndGet(RedisAtomicLong.java:283)

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

**Could you please help me know what situations could lead to this error?**

error log

```bash
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.data.redis.support.atomic.RedisAtomicLong.incrementAndGet(RedisAtomicLong.java:283)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.support.atomic.RedisAtomicLong.getAndIncrement(RedisAtomicLong.java:209)
    at com.config.RedisUtil.getIntentCode(RedisUtil.java:693)
    at com.erp.inventory.manager.InventoryChangeManager.createIntentOrderCode(InventoryChangeManager.java:340)
    at com.erp.inventory.manager.InventoryChangeManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c050fac.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.erp.inventory.manager.InventoryChangeManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd2b48ad.createIntentOrderCode(<generated>)
    at com.erp.inventory.manager.InventoryChangeManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c050fac.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
    at com.erp.inventory.manager.InventoryChangeManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed201035.createIntentOrderCode(<generated>)
    at com.erp.sale.manager.SaleOrderManager.saveSaleOrderInventoryChange(SaleOrderManager.java:1140)
    at com.erp.sale.manager.SaleOrderManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2c81e9f6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.erp.sale.manager.SaleOrderManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$296f95cb.saveSaleOrderInventoryChange(<generated>)
    at com.erp.sale.service.SaleOrderBussiness6Service.executeSaleOrderAuto2503(SaleOrderBussiness6Service.java:344)
    at com.erp.sale.service.SaleOrderBussiness6Service$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a422ebcd.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.erp.sale.service.SaleOrderBussiness6Service$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6dee13b6.executeSaleOrderAuto2503(<generated>)
    at com.erp.sale.service.SaleOrderApprovalService.pass(SaleOrderApprovalService.java:118)
    at com.erp.sale.service.SaleOrderApprovalService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$39c53a33.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.erp.sale.service.SaleOrderApprovalService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f7ae2ea8.pass(<generated>)
    at com.erp.sale.manager.SaleOrderManager.processPassStrategy(SaleOrderManager.java:1367)
    at com.erp.sale.manager.SaleOrderManager.strategyApprovalOrder(SaleOrderManager.java:1352)
    at com.erp.sale.manager.SaleOrderManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2c81e9f6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.erp.sale.manager.SaleOrderManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$296f95cb.strategyApprovalOrder(<generated>)
    at com.erp.sale.manager.SaleOrderManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2c81e9f6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
    at com.erp.sale.manager.SaleOrderManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$49645d53.strategyApprovalOrder(<generated>)
    at com.erp.system.manager.ProcessManager.publishHandleApprovalResult(ProcessManager.java:600)
    at com.erp.system.manager.ProcessManager.handleApprovalOrderStatus(ProcessManager.java:559)
    at com.erp.system.manager.ProcessManager.lambda$approvalProcess$14(ProcessManager.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at com.erp.system.manager.ProcessManager.approvalProcess(ProcessManager.java:341)
    at com.erp.system.manager.ProcessManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d1464e6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.erp.system.manager.ProcessManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37535c9b.approvalProcess(<generated>)
    at com.erp.system.controller.ProcessController.approvalProcess(ProcessController.java:53)
    at com.erp.system.controller.ProcessController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$41ea3e60.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.erp.system.controller.ProcessController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$afb6bf4f.approvalProcess(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3753.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter.doFilter(WebStatFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.support.filter.BodyReaderFilter.doFilter(BodyReaderFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.support.filter.FormDataFilter.doFilter(FormDataFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

my code

RedisUtil.java @Component with springboot

```java
 @Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

public String getIntentCode(String key) {
    ....
    
    RedisAtomicLong entityIdCounter = new RedisAtomicLong(key, Objects.requireNonNull(redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory()));
    
    
    long increment = entityIdCounter.getAndIncrement(); //RedisUtil.java:693 this is error code

    ....
}
```

springboot version : 2.3.7.RELEASE

springboot redis starter : 2.3.7.RELEASE

redis_version:4.0.10
redis : use Single Server

This error occurs in the online environment and is not 100% reproducible. I have made a lot of efforts, but still cannot reproduce it.